# Gradle: how to add dependencies to the specific task?

Tags: gradle

I have dependencies block in my configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile ...
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a task which will build a specific debug artefact:

```
task buildDebugRpm (type: Rpm) {
    requires('java-1.8.0-openjdk', '1.8.0.0', GREATER | EQUAL)
        ...
}
```

Artefact built in this task should include AspectJ libraries in runtime. But I don't want to have them in my common project dependencies.

Is there a way to add `"org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9", "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9"` libs only for this specific task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom configuration and add the dependencies to it:

```
configurations {
    debugRpm {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ...

    debugRpm 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9'
    debugRpm 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9'
}
```

Then include these dependencies in the task:

```
task buildDebugRpm (type: Rpm) {
    ...

    from(configurations.debugRpm) {
        into 'lib'
    }
}
```